# Should I prefer code duplication for better performance?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's say I have two overloaded methods, `void foo(int arg)` and `void foo(int[] args)`. Both do the same processing on the integer parameters. Now, I've implemented them in this way

```
void foo(int arg){
    // Some processing.
}

void foo(int[] args){
    for(int i : args)
        //The same processing as above.
}
```

Now, I know it is a better design principle to avoid code duplication, so the second method can also be implemented as :

```
void foo(int[] args){
    for(int i : args)
        foo(i);
}
```

However, since I am calling the method inside several times, and since method calls add overheads, this approach would make it slower. So, my question is : Which approach should I use?

Comment: You can probably answer this question yourself. Ask yourself, "do I care more about code maintainability or performance?" If the answer is "code maintainability" then you would use the latter. If the answer is "performance" then you would profile the two methods and determine if it was a worthy performance improvement. If your answer is "I care about them equally" then, again,  you need to profile both implementations to help you make your decision. If your answer is "I actually don't care about either of them" then you can pick either piece of code.

Comment: If you are that concerned about performance, you probably wouldn't be using java.  You'd probably be using C/C++/ASM

Comment: For the majority of Java applications the difference in performance will be truly negligible. Imagine that this is ultimately a method being called through a web service, then the overhead of such will be so tremendous much more. As said previously, profile your hotspots, and if this is one of them, you make pragmatic decisions. Until then I would personally let maintainability win.

Comment: If these method are heavily-called/ at the bottom of your stack in performance-constrained area, then optimize them. Otherwise go for maintainability.

Comment: Don't forget that Hotspot JVM may inline the method call if it called enough times, that it seems as a bottleneck. So go for maintenance.

Answer (score 11):

You are talking about a really insignificant overhead. I have a little program that will help you understand how insignificant it is:

```
class Bar {
    void foo(double d) {        
        double y = (d + 1) * d / 7.1 % 31.3 + 13.12 * 20.002;
    }

    void foo1(double[] args) {
        for (double d : args) {
            foo(d);
        }
    }

    void foo2(double[] args) {
        for (double d : args) {
            double y = (d + 1) * d / 7.1 % 31.3 + 13.12 * 20.002;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a test and sample run

```
   public class Main {
        public static void test(int n) {
            System.out.print(n + ",");

            double is[] = new double[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < is.length; i++) {
                is[i] = i * 1.3;
            }

            Bar bar = new Bar();
            long span;

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            bar.foo1(is);
            span = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.print(span + ",");

            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            bar.foo2(is);
            span = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            System.out.print(span + "\n");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            test(10000000);
            test(20000000);
            test(30000000);
            test(40000000);
            test(50000000);
            test(60000000);
        }
    }
```

And here is the a output:

```
10000000,389,383
20000000,743,766
30000000,1130,1113
40000000,1497,1474
50000000,1866,1853
60000000,2243,2239
```

More complex the foo method is, more insignificant the difference will be. So IMHO forget about the performance, think about maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this is just a representative example but you're talking about an extremely small overhead here. In general, I think it's standard practice to design for code maintainability first and for performance second. I'd even go as far as to say that performance optimization shouldn't be brought into consideration until there is a specific performance issue within your codebase (as indicated by a robust performance test suite) that you need to address.

If you're really **that** concerned about performance optimization, you wouldn't be writing in Java anyway....

Comment: interestingly C/C++ may have more aggressive inlining.  So, there may be close to zero function call overhead in these cases

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the first one altogether, and change the second one to:

```
void foo(int...args)
```

with the same code body. Then you won't have either repetition or an extra method call, just the loop-control overhead, which isn't going to kill you.